# In react native, how to convert a base64 image to jpg then save to temp path?

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, react-native, base64

In `react-native`, converting an image to `BASE64` format is easy, with a little help of `react-native-fetch-blob`, I simply do:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64')
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

But, what about the other way around? I know there are some packages out there that does it, but I wonder if it's possible to do it with only `react-native-fetch-blob` or `react-native-fs`?

What I want is that after converting and saving the `BASE64` image to a file, I am able to display it like this:

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: <path/to/converted/image> }}
    style={{ ... }}
/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out it's not tricky at all, suppose I have a `BASE64` image, if I want to convert it to a `JPG`, just use `react-native-fs` like so:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const imageDate = '<some base64 data>';
const imagePath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}image.jpg`;

RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, imageData, 'base64')
    .then(() => console.log('Image converted to jpg and saved at ' + imagePath));
```

That's all

Comment: what about re-sizing the image?

Comment: You can use another library, I personally use ImageEditor from: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-editor