# How can I convert a base64 url to an image(png/jpg) file, in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, base64

I want to convert a base64 URL to an image file in react-native. Is there a package or an easy way to implement this?

Comment: probably duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837840/in-react-native-how-to-convert-a-base64-image-to-jpg-then-save-to-temp-path

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `react-native-fs` like so:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const imageDate = '<some base64 data>';
const imagePath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}image.jpg`;

RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, imageData, 'base64')
    .then(() => console.log('Image converted to jpg and saved at ' + imagePath));
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But what it converted to, is no different from the base64 pathName