# convert image path to base64 - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, base64

i am new to react native. I am using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) to select image from gallery. On image select from gallery, it returns image path like this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.connect/files/Pictures/da154e60-77e0-4364-96a7-ad7fa5acb951.jpg
```

I want to convert this path into base64 string. I can not seem to find a proper way to do this. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. Also please mention how can i convert back from base64.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native Base64 encoding string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255154/react-native-base64-encoding-string)

Comment: There is a `includeBase64` flag that you can include in the request object. Perhaps that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

From path to image you can use [React native fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).
See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576092/13374682)

To convert it back unfortunately you will need to save it, but you can save it under the hood in the temp folder. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844038/13374682)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try `encodeURIComponent()`? I know that it works with links so it may very well work with file paths

Try this:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.connect/files/Pictures/da154e60-77e0-4364-96a7-ad7fa5acb951.jpg'))
```

And to decode ( Though in my experience it is usually not necessary ), use `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: This doesn't convert the path/image into base64.